# Meaning of "visa policy of Ireland grants visa-free entry to all Schengen Annex II nationalities"

Tags: visas, schengen, ireland

I am travelling to Ireland and I was wondering whether I can use my Irish visa to also enter France. From [this similar question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2611/where-can-i-go-with-an-irish-visa-but-without-a-schengen-visa) I see that I must get a separate visa for entering Ireland even if I have a Schengen visa and vise versa. What confuses me is the following sentence from [Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Ireland)

> Visa policy of Ireland is similar to the visa policy of the Schengen
>   Area. It grants visa-free entry to all Schengen Annex II
>   nationalities, except for ...

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Schengen Annex II](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02001R0539-20170611) is the list of countries whose citizens enjoy visa-free access to the Schengen area for short-term visits.  The passage you quote therefore means

> People who enjoy visa-free access to the Schengen area by virtue of their nationality also enjoy visa-free access to Ireland, except for nationals of ...

The comparison is perhaps unhelpful to someone who simply wants to know whether they need a visa for Ireland, especially if that person is not familiar with Schengen policies.

Answer (score 2):

"Annex II" refers to Annex II of the [EU regulation 539/2001](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:32001R0539&from=EN)

Specifically "Schengen Annex II nationalities" refers to citizens from one of the countries contained in this section of that document.