# Flying to Scotland with Irish Visa

Tags: visas, standard-visitor-visas

I'm planning to go to Ireland for a work conference and applied for an Irish single entry visa (I'm Green Card Holder and having Refugee Travel document). Please let me know if we can visit Scotland and fly to Edinburgh with this type of visa?

Answer (score 6):

An Irish visa does not authorize you to enter the United Kingdom unless it is a British-Irish visa scheme visa, in which case it will say BIVS.  Such visas are available only to nationals of India or China who apply for their visas in India or China.

If you do not have a BIVS visa, and you are not eligible to visit the UK without a visa, then you will need to get a UK visa in order to be able to travel to Edinburgh.

Comment: Additionally, to return to Ireland you would need an Irish multi entry visa, as you wouldn't be permitted reentry with a single entry one.

Comment: @JakeDot are you certain that that is true?  CTA rules are terribly confusing.  Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: [This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/138746/95392) mentions that for visa holders (those not travelling visa-free) the conditions of the visa apply. That would mean not being able to return on a single entry visa. I'm not sure where but in the last week or so I think I saw an answer clarifying that in the last week or so.

Comment: It isn't the one I thought, but [here in the comments](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/2614/95392) it's mentioned that even entering NI by land is not allowed with a single entry visa (which is entirely logical of course).